# How to record video from iPhone camera in iOS 9 objective c?

Tags: objective-c

hello I need to build app that record video from iPhone camera.
I search in the net and not found notting that works in iOS 9.
I get this code from this git project : 
https://github.com/versluis/Video-Recorder

This code open camera but not allow Me to take a video.

```
- (IBAction)recordButton:(id)sender {

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;

    NSArray *mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"I'm afraid there's no camera on this device!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dang!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
    }
}

 - (IBAction)playbackButton:(id)sender {

// pick a video from the documents directory
NSURL *video = [self grabFileURL:@"video.mov"];

// create a movie player view controller
MPMoviePlayerViewController * controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:video];
[controller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[controller.moviePlayer play];

// and present it
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];

}


#pragma mark - Delegate Methods

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

// user hit cancel
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// grab our movie URL
NSURL *chosenMovie = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

// save it to the documents directory
NSURL *fileURL = [self grabFileURL:@"video.mov"];
NSData *movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chosenMovie];
[movieData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];

// save it to the Camera Roll
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([chosenMovie path], nil, nil, nil);

// and dismiss the picker
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (NSURL*)grabFileURL:(NSString *)fileName {

// find Documents directory
NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

// append a file name to it
documentsURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

return documentsURL;
}
```

Comment: I edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ray](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios) gave pretty good tutorial about this. Hope it helped.